# How can I scrape Google Search results in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape Google Search results in Heroku but when I am using simple request and bs4 to scrape but my request is getting blocked due to its cookies.

I have also attached a image of the Google response on searching in Heroku:

[image: Heroku Google Search result]

Answer (score 1):

It might be because there's [no `user-agent` specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent). For example, default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit.

Another thing that might happen is you receive a different HTML with some sort of an error. `User-agent` fakes user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

I wrote a dedicated blog about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) that cover multiple solutions.

[Pass `user-agent` in request `headers`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}
requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

Also, it's just a cookie consent. Everything is accessible for scraping. If you want to remove it, pass a specific cookie (*dev tools -> network -> fetch/xhr -> headers - look for cookie*) to [request `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers), or remove an element with [`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) `bs4` method which will remove an element from the HTML tree.

---

Example code to extract *URL* and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

# this URL params is taken from the actual Google search URL
# and transformed to a more readable format
params = {
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",   # query
  "gl": "us",                                 # country to search from
  "hl": "en",                                 # language
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

  print(link, sep='\n')

--------
'''
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/47hw1g/what_does_katana_mean_it_means_japanese_sword_2/
... other links
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve exactly the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Essentially, the main difference in your example is that you don't have to figure out how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines, create a parser from scratch and maintain it over time.

The only thing that really needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "samurai cop what does katana mean",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['link'])
  print()

--------
'''
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paTW3wOyIYw
https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1060647
https://www.reddit.com/r/NewTubers/comments/47hw1g/what_does_katana_mean_it_means_japanese_sword_2/
... other links
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.